# Given a File ID (fid) how can I get the HTML that represents that fid?

Tags: 7, files, theming

I'm looking to do something like this

```
$fid = 15;
$file = (array)file_load($fid);
$content = drupal_render($file);
echo $content;
```

- [file_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_load/7)
- [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

And specifically this fid is from the 7.x-2.x version of the [media module](http://drupal.org/project/media).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works for me. For videos via the media module:

```
<?php
  $file = file_load($fid);
  if (strpos($file->filemime, 'video/') !== 0) {
    return;
  }
  $key = 'media_' . substr($file->filemime, 6) . '_video';
  $formatter_info = file_info_formatter_types($key);
  $content = array();
  $content['#theme'] = $key;
  $content['#uri'] = $file->uri;
  if (isset($formatter_info['default settings'])) {
    $content['#options'] = $formatter_info['default settings'];
  }

  $rendered = drupal_render($content);
  return $rendered;
?>
```

And for images; this shows you what presets are available (`#style_name`)

```
<?php
$styles = image_styles();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($styles, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>
```

And this will render the file

```
<?php
$file = file_load($fid);
$image = image_load($file->uri);
$content = array(
  'file' => array(
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#style_name' => 'large',
    '#path' => $image->source,
    '#width' => $image->info['width'],
    '#height' => $image->info['height'],
  ),
);
echo drupal_render($content);
?>
```

Note that [image_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--image.inc/function/image_load/7) performs I/O.

And for the reverse; given a filename get a fid.

```
<?php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'file')
  ->propertyCondition('filename', basename($filename))
  ->execute();
foreach ($result['file'] as $values) {
  $fid = $values->fid;
  break;
}
echo $fid
?>
```

Given media embed code, get a FID.

```
<?php
$file = media_parse_to_file($embed_code);
if (empty($file->fid)) {
  return FALSE;
}
return $file->fid;
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain "$key = 'media_' . substr($file->filemime, 6) . '_video';" ? I am trying to render a video from fid. I don't want to use any video field and I don't have any custom video formats.

Comment: @TejasVaidya if `$file->filemime = video/youtube` then the key will end up being 'media_youtube_video' which will use the theme function inside of https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube (see [media_youtube_theme()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/media_youtube/tree/media_youtube.module#n36))

Comment: If you want to render the original image just use #theme => 'image' and remove '#style_name' => 'large'

Answer (score 7):

You are misapplying `drupal_render()` in your example. `drupal_render()` holds the content to be displayed and the instructions for how to render it in an array so that all content can be modified by other modules, until the last moment before  displaying.  Everything is loaded in the `drupal_render()` argument `&$elements`, which is the argument for the function.  `drupal_render()` does not return rendered elements from variables passed in arguments.

Look at the [theme API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) for a series of functions that will provide HTML for various content elements including files.

Comment: hate to say this but [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug-backtrace) told me otherwise. That's why I went with [drupal_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) in my answer/question.

Answer (score 3):

The function you are probably looking for is [file_get_content_headers()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_get_content_headers/7), which sets the headers for allowing a file to be downloaded, or (if the file is a text file, or an image) to be viewed inline.

The function requires a file object as returned by [file_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_load_multiple/7), [file_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_load/7), or [entity_load('file')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_load/7).