# Access uploaded file by ID

Tags: webforms, files

I have a webform that allows users to upload their CV/Resume's. The webform is sending me the file ID. I know that the URL for accessing those files is https:// example.com/sites/default/files/webform/myfilename.

Can I access the file using the file ID instead of its name, for example https:// example.com/sites/default/files/webform?fileid=1502?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this in code, I believe that this question has already been answered:

[Given a File ID (fid) how can I get the HTML that represents that fid?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/given-a-file-id-fid-how-can-i-get-the-html-that-represents-that-fid)

You can also access the file's page at yoursiteurl/file/fid, but this isn't a direct link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the drupal `file_load()` function to load the uploaded file.

```
<?php

$fid= 1502;
$file = file_load($fid);

?>
```

It will return the details of a file in the form of an array.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

`file_load()` has been deprecated

Instead, in a custom module you can use the function `Drupal\file\Entity\file::load($fid)` to load a file with the file ID that is present in the webform submission values

Here is an example :

```
  use Drupal\file\Entity;

  function student_support_form_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){

     $values = $form_state->getValues();

       if(!empty($values['file'])){
         $file = Entity\File::load($values['file']);
         $values['file'] = $file->getFileUri();
       }
     ...
    }
```

Here 'file' is the key of your webform fileUpload element and $values['file'] would be an integer.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) That's very interesting indeed. Unfortunately I doubt this answers OP's question...

Comment: This seems a comment for a previous answer. As for answering the question, I think none of the answers really answered it, since the OP seems to ask about a link to access the uploaded file given its ID.